# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment. Why are the initialized values not assigned when entering the function

Tags: python-3.x

Why is that the initialized variables x and y are not assigned when entering the functions? Because they are not in any class??

```
print("Start program")
x = 10
print(x)
y = 10
print(y)

def _return_string():
    if type(x) == "<class 'int'>":
        print("x is of type integer")
        x = str(x)
    else:
        print("x is of type string")
    if type(y) == "<class 'int'>":
        print("y is of type integer")
        y = str(y)
    else:
        print("y is of type string")
    print("concatenate x and y:",x+y)

def _return_integer():
    # x = 10
    # y = 20
    if type(x) == "<class 'str'>":
        print("x is of type string")
        x = int(x)
    else:
        print("x is of type integer")
    if type(y) == "<class 'str'>":
        print("y is of type string")
        x = int(y)
    else:
        print("y is of type integer")
    print("sum of x and y:",x+y)\

_return_integer()
```

Why are the initialized values not assigned when entering the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any variable which is changed or created inside of a function is local, if it hasn't been declared as a global variable. To tell Python, that we want to use the global variable, we have to explicitly state this by using the keyword "global".

```
def _return_integer():
    global x
    global y
    if type(x) == "<class 'str'>":
        print("x is of type string")
        x = int(x)
    ....
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. Also figured if type(x) == "<class 'str'>": is simply if type(x) == str: